# How to pass value from classic asp to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I am new to classic asp.

An asp page gets the urlparameters and depending on the url parameters it calls and loads the appropriate html pages.

I need to display some of the url parameters in the html page, which needs to be passed from the classic asp page? How can it be achieved?

Comment: Using [Request.QueryString("urlParameter")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and then %variable% within the html element?

Comment: you can embed the params as hidden form values, json in a script tag, even attributes...

Comment: *DON'T* display URL parameters in your HTML. At least not without properly sanitizing them. Otherwise you're open to script injection

Comment: @dandavis Can you please explain in detail?

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked about JavaScript, here is a rough example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('URL parameter value is: <%=Replace(Request.QueryString("paramnamehere"), "'", "\'")%>');
</script>
```

Replace "paramnamehere" with the name of the URL parameter and you'll see its value as client side alert dialog.